# How can I format 3 columns in IE8 while also using flexie.js?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have 3 columns, each with separate options. I would like them to display from left to right, which they do, except in IE8. We're using a plugin called  [Flexie.js.](http://flexiejs.com/)  Currently, when rendering the page in IE8, the 3rd column on the right ends up under the middle column. All three columns have the same attributes:

```
min-width:210px;
max-width:290px;
margin-right:20px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
```

Any ideas?